# Allow Internal CA to sign CSR

Tags: openssl, certificate, certificate-authority, csr

So as it says, how am I supposed to allow Internal CA to sign CSR?

This would be for scenarios where you cannot easily replace a private key for a client so the preferred process uses CSR's instead.

Is it even possible?

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/ca.html#EXAMPLES There's a ton of guides for this, but it's not a simple process if you don't already have a CA provisioned.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek I'm not really sure what You mean by "Provisioned CA"? Does that mean that Internal CA already exists, or something?

Comment: Right, do you already have an internal CA set up and the CA certificate installed as trusted on the clients? If yes, you can directly sign the CSR using the `openssl ca` subcommand and the output file will work.

Comment: Alright, got it. I will prototype it asap. Thank You! @AndrewDomaszek

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank You @AndrewDomaszek .
Can You post the comment as an answer so I can vote it and select it as solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of [openssl ca subcommand examples on the manpage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/ca.html#EXAMPLES). The standard method of signing a CSR is the same, regardless of how you generate it or what you generate it from. For example, signing using the default extensions for this CA's config:

```
openssl ca -in csr.pem -out newcert.pem
```

This requires the internal CA already be set up for cert signing, and the internal CA's certificate be added to the trust root stores of any clients that may need to validate it.